# ActiveRecord Model exists? running slow - solution found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, newrelic, heroku-postgres

I spent ages trying to track this down, so I thought I'd post my experience here in case anybody else has the same issue.

Running Rails 6.1.1 on Heroku. Started noticing reports of critical response time in Heroku metrics. Went into New Relic where it reported the offender..

> model_controller#update..
> ActiveRecord Model exists? Average time 522ms

Eventually noticed the following on local development machine when triggering `model_controller#update`

> Model Exists? (490.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "model" WHERE LOWER("model"."field") = LOWER($1) AND ""."id" != $2 LIMIT $3

Despite the fact that field on model is an index, Postrgres wasn't using the index with this query.

Origin of this problem was the validation on Model.. see below; sharing your knowledge, Q&A-style

Answer (score 2):

Origin of this problem was the validation on Model

> validates :field, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

Changed to..

> validates :field, presence: true, uniqueness: true, if: :field_changed?

Changed rest of code to make sure field is always lowercase. Must say, New Relic is a terrific piece of kit, and is a great help when running an app.

Comment: `Despite the fact that field on model is an index, Postrgres wasn't using the index with this query` Postgres doesn't index or cache function calls. I encountered a signifigant slow down in performance when using `LOWER` in a search.

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery PostgreSQL can [index an expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) such as `lower(some_column)` but it might take a bit of chicanery to get Rails to create such an index.

Comment: @muistooshort maybe I was thinking of the caching out of the box :P